# How can I access the bound value of a <select>'s currently selected <option>?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Say I am making a simple component which wraps a `<select>`. This component supports `v-model`, as documented [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

```js
Vue.component('custom-select', {
  template: '#component',
  props: ['options', 'value'],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="component">
  <div id="component">
    <select :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
      <option v-for='option in options' :value="option">
        <slot v-bind="{ option }"></slot>
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</script>
```

This works fine if the options are strings. However, if they are a different type (e.g. objects), then the values emitted are cast to strings (e.g. `'[object Object]'`). This is because `$event.target.value` pulls the value from the DOM, which will always be a string type.

**Is there a way to get the original bound value of the selected `<option>`?** I'm aware of `v-model` as an option, but it complicates things as it requires adding watchers.

---

**EDIT** I have discovered that Vue seems to assign the original bound value to the `_value` property on the DOM node, though I'm not sure if accessing that is a good idea since it's underscore prefixed and seems to be undocumented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I still haven't found an exact solution to my original question, I've found a design pattern that I think solves the issue satisfactorily. By using a computed property with a getter and setter, I can use `v-model` on the `<select>` without needing watchers or any internal component state.

```js
Vue.component('custom-select', {
  template: '#component',
  props: ['options', 'value'],
  computed: {
    valueProxy: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.$emit('input', newValue);
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="component">
  <div id="component">
    <select v-model="valueProxy">
      <option v-for='option in options' :value="option">
        <slot v-bind="{ option }"></slot>
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `options` prop is an array of object as below
You can change the event emitter of child component to return object instead of string like this:

```css
<style>
  [v-cloak] {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<!-- // App -->
<div id="app">
  <div v-cloak>
    Value in parent: {{selectedValue}}
    <br><br>
    <custom-select :options='selectOptions' v-model='selectedValue'></custom-select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- // JS Code -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="component">
  <div id="component">
    <select @change="$emit('input', options.find(option => option.value == $event.target.value))">
      <option v-for='option in options' :value="option.value">
        {{ option.text }}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
</script>
<script>
  // Mount App
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
      return {
        selectOptions: [
          { text: 'Apple', value: 'apple', price: '10' },
          { text: 'Banana', value: 'banana', price: '20' },
          { text: 'Strawberry', value: 'strawberry', price: '30' },
        ],
        selectedValue: {}
      }
    },
    // Custom component
    components: {
      'custom-select': Vue.component('custom-select', {
        template: '#component',
        props: ['options', 'value'],
      })
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround, though not a proper solution because it requires all items to have a string-based ID

Comment: @Ryan I am not sure what kind of input data you have. Can you share the sample inputs?

Comment: I am looking for a solution that would work for an array of any arbitrary data types.

Comment: @Ryan few examples would help.